# pyspark sql parseExpression with cte results with mismatched input 'AS' expecting {<EOF>, '-'}

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

trying to write a unit test that validates spark sql.  I'm on python.  I tried this:

```
    spark = SparkSession.builder
            .master('local[1]')
            .appName('local-spark-unittest')
            .config("spark.sql.legacy.createHiveTableByDefault", "false")
            .getOrCreate()
    try:
        parser = spark._jsparkSession.sessionState().sqlParser()
        parser.parseExpression("""WITH t AS (SELECT 1) SELECT * FROM t""")
        print('Validation successful')
    except ParseException as e:
        print('Validation failed')
```

I get as a result:

```
        except py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError as e:
            converted = convert_exception(e.java_exception)
            if not isinstance(converted, UnknownException):
                # Hide where the exception came from that shows a non-Pythonic
                # JVM exception message.
>               raise converted from None
E               pyspark.sql.utils.ParseException: 
E               mismatched input 'AS' expecting {<EOF>, '-'}(line 2, pos 12)
```

If I run the same with just `parser.parseExpression("SELECT 1")` Then it passes with no issues.

Comment: You have to name your column in your cte - `select 1 as foo`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding brackets around the query will make it work:

```py
parser.parseExpression("""(WITH t AS (SELECT 1) SELECT * FROM t)""")
```